# Math.random() in Java, how is this possible?

Tags: java, math

Currently in class, learning about math in Java

I got speechless when my teacher showed me this formula?

```
if ((int)(Math.random() * 15) == 1) {
```

How can something * 15 be 1?

Comment: (1/15) * 15 = 1.

Comment: `1/15 * 15 == 1` - see? it's possible

Comment: Math.random generates a number between `0.0` and `1.0`, as additional info to the other commands

Comment: From the JavaDoc on `Math.random()`: `Returns a double value with a positive sign, greater than or equal to 0.0 and less than 1.0` - so multiplying that with 15 and casting to `int` makes it effectively a random number between 0 and 14 (inclusive).

Comment: Oh, I thought Math.random generated a number between 0.0 and 100.0
My bad, thanks for the help!

Comment: Hint: if you are confused ... read the javadoc!

Comment: As the left hand side is a random value between 0 and 14, you could have put any value between 0 and 14 on the right hand side. It just has a 1 in 15 chance of being true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because of the cast to integer

> (int) Math.random()

You see Math.random() gives a random number between 0.0 and 1.0
when you cast to an integer you are effectively saying - " Throw out all the decimal places"

So if you had 0.5 doing `(int) Math.random()` would give you 0.

Now looking at your code, you'd have something like this

Assuming Math.random() gives 0.3, you'd have

`((int)(0.3 * 15) == 1)` which will be `((int)(4.5) == 1)` now remember what casting to `int` does? throw out the decimal places. So we are left with `if (4 == 1)`.

In this case the condition will be false so the code in the if won't run but there is a chance that you would have a number like 1.xx after multiplying.

Answer (score 3):

Suppose Math.random returns 0.08907633950002491

Now according to your formula

```
0.08907633950002491*15 it returns 1.3361450925003737
```

after int type cast it will be 1

(`int)(Math.random() * 15) == 1 returns true`

Answer (score 1):

> The java.lang.Math.random() returns a double value with a positive
>   sign, greater than or equal to 0.0 and less than 1.0.

x * 15 = 1

x = 1/15

So X is a double value from interval 0-1. Everything is correct.

Comment: keep in mind that it gets cast to an int, so bascily it´s `x*15 = 1 && x*15<2`.

Comment: @KevinEsche do you mean `x*15 >= 1 && x*15<2`

Comment: @nafas ah yeah i meant `x*15 >= 1`.